# Range class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have the `lst2 = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]` and want to get the 3 middle elements from a new list. How can I proceed?

I am unsure on how I can get them to add +1 for each. Example:

```
for i in range(1,100,10)
    print(i)
```

This would only give me a list with [1,11,21,31,41,51...], when I am in want of a list that would go more like: [11,22,33,44...].

Comment: So increase your stepsize by 1 to 11...

Comment: `lst = list(range(11, 78, 11))` (the arguments are: start, stop [exclusive], step). and to be picky: `range` is a class in python and not a function.

Comment: If I use the same code, that would leave me a list with [11, 21, 31, 41, 51,...]. How can I add +1 to each of these?

Comment: `[i+1 for i in lst]`...

Comment: Thanks @hiroprotagonist that worked perfectly! I don't mind that you're also informing me that it's a class and not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop = 100
result = []

for i in range(11,stop, 10):
  result.append(i)

print(result)
```

https://repl.it/KR6P

Comment: `result = list(range(11, stop, 10))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved it by doing it like this:

`for i in range(33,67,11):
    print(i)`

Kinda unsure why people downvote this though